# Postgres socket disconnect event when doing a reboot from AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have an AWS Postgres cluster with 2 instances, and we are using `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` (actually `pg_notify` from the db) notifications. It seems though that when restarting Postgres with RDS, we don't get any event in the error callback, nor any of the other ones, drain, end. Below is a sample of how the client has been initalized using the `pg` package:

```
this.client = new Client({ connectionString });
this.client.on('error', async error => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
});
```

Are we missing anything? If we don't get notified of the server reboot, we are losing notifications, since the new notifications from the server are not being listened to anymore (we would need a new `LISTEN` query), so this behaviour should not be normal.